# Compatibility mode with CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following folder structure for one of my tools:

- scripts
- Original

In my scripts folder I have a .bat-script which runs a .exe-file in my Original-folder. This .exe requires a few compatibility modes like:

- run with Windows 98
- run at 640x480
- run 265bit mode
- disable fullscreen optimizations

Therefore my question is - how do you set all these compatibility options with in a script when you not know the whole path (just that you have to go one directory up and into the specified path) ?

Thank you for your help
Greetings

Comment: Put a .lnk file into Original, and execute the executable through that link. Though, of course, this not a programming question.

Comment: This question should be moved to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the __COMPAT_LAYER variable (note the two underscores before `COMPAT` and one underscore before `LAYER`), which sets compatibility settings for an instance of cmd. It can take multiple settings in a space-separated list.

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=Win98 640x480 256Color DisableDXMaximizedWindowedMode
```

- `Win98` runs the program in compatibility mode for Windows 98/ME
- `640x480` runs in 640x480
- `256color` runs in 256 colors
- `DisableDXMaximizedWindowedMode` disables fullscreen optimizations

And then run the program after that. Relative to the directory that the batch script is in, "one directory up and into the specified path" is `"%~dp0..\folder"`, assuming that the folder you're trying to enter is called "folder."

Once the program is done, you can unset the variable with `set __COMPAT_LAYER=`.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. It's not set in the properties (or doesn't it has to be?) even when i tried it in the same directory.

Comment: It's not going to check the boxes for you, but it will run the program as if they were.